# Display image in screen(view) background

Tags: oracle-adf, hybrid-mobile-app, oracle-adf-mobile

I want to display image at background of PanelPage which is top most view in ADF mobile.  I want to set image at background.

My AMX file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<amx:view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:amx="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/mf/amx"
          xmlns:dvtm="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/mf/amx/dvt" >

 <amx:panelPage id="pp1" inlineStyle='background-image:url("image/custom_cell_image.png");'>

  <amx:facet name="header">
      <amx:outputText value="Requition Line" id="ot1"/>
    </amx:facet>
    <amx:facet name="primary">
      <amx:commandButton id="cb1" text="Requisition" inlineStyle="font-size:small;" action="__back"/>
    </amx:facet>
    <amx:facet name="footer">
      <amx:commandButton id="cb2" action="back" text="Approve" styleClass="adfmf-commandButton-default"/>
            <amx:commandButton text="Reject" id="cb3"/>
            <amx:commandButton text="Request More Info" id="cb4"/>
    </amx:facet>
    <amx:commandButton text="commandButton1" id="cb5"/>
  </amx:panelPage>
</amx:view>
```

I set image url, but it is not effected.  If I set background color, then it is effected.

Comment: Did you find a solution on this? My bg image can be set,but not complete, it gets cut if component is small than image and I want to set with variable sizes of device, i.e, xhdpi, mdpi, ldpi. I am stuck on it.

Answer (score 0):

If using skinning on iOS

1. image file in /app/ApplicationController/public_html/resources
2. Css file located at /app/ApplicationController/public_html/resources/css
3. in .css file

> ```
> .panel-page-custom {
>     background-image: url("../bg.png");
> }
> ```

1. in amx page

> amx:panelPage styleClass=panel-page-custom